# Shuffling String

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that scrambles a 4 letter string inputted by the user. (example TEST can be scrambled like tset, ttse etc...) Well I have a program that works but it is limited to a 4 element char array, and I want to know if there is any way to make it so I don't have to have the size pre-determined.

```
//4 letter word scrambler (ex. test tets tset...)
int counter=0;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str[4];
    cout << "Please enter a  word: "; //ask for input
    cin >> str;
    counter+=1; // set counter to 1 
    cout << counter << " " << str << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){// iteration through one full loop in array
        swap(str[i], str[i+1]); //swap two elements as iterates through array
        counter+=1;//add 1 to counter each time
        cout <<counter<<" "<< str << endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        swap(str[i], str[i+1]);
        counter+=1;
        cout << counter<< " " << str << endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            swap(str[i], str[i+1]);
        counter+=1;
        cout << counter << " " << str << endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            swap(str[i], str[i+1]);
        counter+=1;
        cout << counter << " " << str << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just do a simple [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle. I don't use C++, so there might be something awesome already to do this -- but the wiki article is pretty good and it's darn-simple algorithm. Note how the shuffle runs through the *entire* array (this is what makes it extendible to any-sized collection). You can use this implementation to "output in place" (you don't need to store the shuffled array results!).

Comment: do you seek all the permutation or do you want it to be random?

Comment: Your initial solution gives exactly 12 solutions, whatever happens, so I think it's wrong in many cases. Do you want to distinguish differently positioned equal characters or not? So, you want the permutations with or without repetitions? _(resultcount for **TTTT** is **4!** or **1** ?)_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to shuffle the string once or print all permutations of the letters in the word. Both are fairly simple using the C++ Standard Library.

This first bit of code does a single random shuffle:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please enter a  word: "; //ask for input
    cin >> str;
    random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end());
    cout << str << '\n';
}
```

The following prints all permutations of the string:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please enter a  word: "; //ask for input
    cin >> str;
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    do {
        cout << str << '\n';
    } while (next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to scramble a string of length N.
Iterate through the string from character `0 -> n-1`.
Select two random indices `i,j`  (via `random(n)` ) at each iteration, and swap those two indices.
You can prove that that will be a uniformly random scrambling.

Comment: do I use srand() and rand()? those are the only random functions I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an std::string instead of a char[4]. (Strings are always preferable to char[] anyway). Your code would then be:

> ```
> string str;
> cout << "Please enter a  word: "; //ask for input
> cin >> str;
> counter+=1; // set counter to 1 
> cout << counter << " " << str << endl;
> for (int i=0;i<str.size();i++){
>      // iteration through one full loop in array
> ```

And for a better way to shuffle the string check out:

```
std::next_permutation
```